# Items inside flexbox not interactable

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have an interactive map generated using svg paths. Whenever I click a path, a container should appear containing some infos and links regarding that area.

The problem I have encountered is that nothing inside this container can be interacted with (ie. click links).

Items inside the container are generated using JS from a JSON file.
JSON reading works, although not over codepen, i dont know why (doesnt matter). You can see the code live [here](https://viorelbaltaretu.ro/harta-activitate-teritoriu/).

Here's my code: https://codepen.io/yasinibraim/pen/YzVVBMm

Short summary of the code:

- SVG map inside svgContainer div
- responsive info container inside containerInfo div
- items inside containerInfo div generated inside clickUAT JS function. JSON fetched inside loadJSON function.

This is how i generate the content of containerInfo:

```
for (let i in actual_JSON){
        if(actual_JSON[i].uat == caller){
            if(firstItem == 1){
                //newElement = document.createElement("ul");
            }
            header = document.createElement("p");
            newElement = document.createTextNode (actual_JSON[i].title);
            header.appendChild(newElement);
            newElement = document.createElement ("a");
            newElement.setAttribute('href',actual_JSON[i].link);
            newElement.innerHTML = "Citește";
            header.appendChild(newElement);
            container.appendChild(header);
        }
            console.log(actual_JSON[i].Title);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the links inside `<div id="containerInfo" class="fadeIn">` when you click on a region?

This is because you have `pointer-events: none;` on the container, which will affect the children as well.

You either need to add pointer events to `<a>` element, or add pointer events back to `#containerInfo` when it becomes visible.